# searching an array of strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have an array of strings and i need to search whether the strings of the array exits in database or not. i am using following query:

```
foreach($array as $s)
{   
if(preg_match('/^(\bpho)\w+\b$/', $s))
{ 
    $query="select * from dictionary where words REGEXP '^".$s."$'";
    $result=$db->query($query) or die($db->error);
    if($result)
    {
    $count += $result->num_rows;
    }
}
}
```

but this query taking long time to execute. PLease provide a solution to reduce the searching time

Comment: if you can narrow your search to specific table or column then you can use index on that particular columns

Comment: Why are you using `REGEXP` when it looks like you're doing exact matches? Does `$array` contain regular expressions?

Comment: yes, u can see i am searching  all the elements that starts with 'pho'.

Comment: Does `$array` contain things like `pho\d*`, i.e. are there regular expression operators in `$array`? Or are they just words like `phonetic`?

Comment: I understand why you're using `preg_match`, my question is why you're using `WHERE words REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine all the search strings into a single regular expression using alternation.

```
$searches = array();
foreach ($array as $s) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\bpho)\w+\b$/', $s)) {
        $searches[] = "($s)";
    }
}
$regexp = '^(' . implode('|', $searches) . ')$';
$query="select 1 from dictionary where words REGEXP '$regexp'";
$result=$db->query($query) or die($db->error);
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

If `$array` doesn't contain regular expressions, you don't need to use the SQL `REGEXP` operator. You can use `IN`:

```
$searches = array();
foreach ($array as $s) {
    if (preg_match('/^(\bpho)\w+\b$/', $s)) {
        $searches[] = "'$s'";
    }
}
$in_list = implode(',', $searches);
$query="select 1 from dictionary where words IN ($in_list)";
$result=$db->query($query) or die($db->error);
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem here is about your code. I think you should optimize your database.
I'm not very good at it but I think you could add indexes in your database to speed up the research

Comment: Indexes only have limited ability to optimize REGEXP matching.

Comment: and it's exactly what he need no?

Comment: Maybe you should be more specific. What types of optimizations do you recommend to make the regular expression matching faster?

Comment: You call that "more specific"?

Answer (score 0):

Searching the whole database is a large job, I think a better way is you can cache some parts of the database, and than search in the cache. Redis is very good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Modify your query so that is doesn't select all table columns - that is a waste of resources. Instead, just let the database count the number of rows containing the search query and return back only a single answer (matches):

$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS matches FROM dictionary WHERE words REGEXP '^".$s."$'";

2. How are you indexing your database? If your **words** column is not indexed properly, then your regexp would take a long time. Examine your database structure and potentially add indexing to the **words** column.

P.S. And don't forget to fetch the **matches** column instead of using **num_rows**